# Grep of multiple commands

Tags: grep

I want to search for a string (not a pattern at the moment), print only once the matched string and the number of matched lines.

common sense says I have to do this:

```
grep -o "APPLICATION=MULTIRING" filename.csv | grep -c "APPLICATION=MULTIRING"
```

or this:

```
grep -o "APPLICATION=MULTIRING" filename.csv | grep -c ""
```

but non works. Apperently `-c` kills any other command.. why?

Comment: It works to me. Also, `grep -o` gives one result per line. Hence, instead of `grep -c` you can use `wc -l` to count the number of matches.

Comment: grep -o "APPLICATION=MULTIRING" filename.csv | wc -l prints only the number of appearences and not "APPLICATION=MULTIRING". still can't figure why.

Answer (score 0):

In real terms what you've put in says:

"Look for 'APPLICATION=MULTIRING' in filename.csv, then look through these results and count the occurances"

Try
    grep -o "APPLICATION-MULTIRING" in filename.csv | wc -l

Which, if I'm remembering rightly, will count the occurances outputted.

grep -c doesn't kill other commands, but piping a command into it means it will act as a filter.

Comment: Ah, while I was typing this, @fedorqui seems to have said pretty much the same.

Comment: grep -o "APPLICATION=MULTIRING" filename.csv | wc -l prints only the number of appearences and not "APPLICATION=MULTIRING". still can't figure why.

Answer (score 0):

Some thing like this? -- Definitely a cheap trick

```
awk '/APPLICATION=MULTIRING/ {count++} END {print "APPLICATION=MULTIRING", count }' filename.csv
```